# I am using PHPMailer for first time

Tags: php, mysql

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting ',' or ')' in C:\xampp\htdocs\Project\lost-password.php

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST["forgot_pass"])){
    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$_POST['email']);
    $query ="SELECT *FROM users WHERE user_email = '{$email}' ";
    $for_query = mysqli_query($connection,$query);
    if(mysqli_num_rows($for_query)>0){
        $str = "0123456789acdsvfetryuhgbhjikolpmnbva";
        $str = str_shuffle($str);
        $str = substr($str,0,10);
        $up_query = "UPDATE users SET token='$str', token_expire=DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 5 MINUTE) WHERE user_email= '{$email}'";
        $update_q = mysqli_query($connection,$up_query);
        require_once "PHPMailer/PHPMailer.php";
        require_once "PHPMailer/Exception.php";
        $mail =new PHPMailer();
        $mail->addAddress($email);

        //getting error here     
        $mail->setFrom( address: 'exa@example.com', name: 'ABC');
        $mail->Subject = 'Reset Password';

        //getting error here        
        $mail->isHTML(isHtml: true);
        $mail->Body="
        Hi,<br><br>
        In order to reset your password, please click on the link below:<br>
        <a href=>n</a><br><br> ";
        ?>
```

Comment: Yes you are, because what you've written in that area isn't PHP.

Comment: `$mail->setFrom('exa@example.com', 'ABC');`

Comment: Also you must close the two if "if(mysqli_num_rows($for_query)>0){" and "if(isset($_POST["forgot_pass"])){" to Avoid the Parse Error.

Comment: Next error will be `Expected '}' ...`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are passing in named parameters but those things do not exist in PHP. So instead of doing:

```
$mail->setFrom( address: 'exa@example.com', name: 'ABC');
```

you should call the method like:

```
$mail->setFrom('exa@example.com', 'ABC');
```

You should also do the same for `$mail->isHTML(isHtml: true)`, change that to `$mail->isHTML(true)`

Comment: i did as u said now i'm getting this error Fatal error: Class 'PHPMailer' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\Project/lost-password.php on line

Comment: That has to do with your autoloading (or probably the absence of it). Please read the section with the `use` and `require` statements in the documentation (https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer#installation--loading)

Comment: it works but showing in spam  mail is there any problem

Comment: There are a lot of reasons that your mail can get marked as spam, but that's outside the scope of your original question. To understand what's going wrong you can start with reading https://stackoverflow.com/a/6567250/1882337 and by validating the headers of the e-mail that was sent.

Comment: i have one doubt the mail sent only once why?